# How to check event execution duration in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql 5.7 and I scheduled some simple BI calculation using events.

The events are scheduled every 1 hour and I need to know duration of each execution to evaluate if the event can be scheduled every 30 mins.

I can use

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.events;
```

to find events' status, last run time, last altered time, etc. But where to find the execution log of events?

Comment: There is no log for scheduled events, unless they throw exceptions... in which case, you'll find an error written to the standard MySQL "hostname.err" error log.

Comment: measure the time in your client?